# Select a div if it contains all specified elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm attempting to select the `.item` div which contains both `tagOne` and `tagTwo` `span` elements.

My `div` structure is as follows:

```
<div id="items">

    <div id="block1" class="item">
        <span class="tagOne tag">One</span>
        <span class="tagTwo tag">Two</span>
    </div>

    <div id="block2" class="item">
        <span class="tagOne tag">Java</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Using the following jQuery I'm able to locate the tags (with their parent `div`'s) separately.

```
var blocks =  $('#items .item');

blocks.filter('.item').find('[class*="tagOne"]').parent();
blocks.filter('.item').find('[class*="tagTwo"]').parent();
```

However, once I try to combine them to narrow it down to the one `div` that **contains them both**, I get no results and I can't seem to work out why!

```
blocks.filter('.item').find('[class*="tagOne"][class*="tagTwo"]');
```

My understanding is that the comma syntax will create an OR expression, and without creates an AND expression. I'm after the AND expression as I only want to return the div that contains all the criteria, or nothing at all.

---

Note: I'm doing it this way because I'm creating a toggle-filter based on the tags, and the criteria (i.e. `tagOne, tagTwo`) is a concatenation of the tags selected by the user (not shown) so it is preferable to try to do it in one operation.

---

**EDIT:** Moved duplicate `id`'s to `class` names instead to make it valid and tweaked JavaScript code accordingly.

Comment: you have to use `,`. `blocks.filter('.item').find('[id="tagOne"],[id="tagTwo"]');`

Comment: JavaScript will not work reliably when you have multiple elements sharing the same `id`, which - incidentally - also renders your HTML invalid. If you need to have multiple elements with a *common* identifier then you should use a class-name, not an `id`.

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks, you're right. I'll also look at changing this

Comment: @AnkitKathiriya My understanding is that a comma depicts OR syntax so it will return all instances. What I'm trying to do is return the div which contains all required elements, or nothing at all

Comment: you should use `class`. and perform check `blocks.filter('.item').find('.tagOne.tagTwo');` if both class present then it will return. means `AND`.

Comment: @AnkitKathiriya Thanks for the recommendation. I've changed my code so that it doesn't use ID's at all (due to the certainty of duplication). I've edited my question to reflect this. However, your code recommendation still returns nothing. One or the other class names works, but not them both combined. Again, this code needs to look over multiple elements in the div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the **ID should be unique**. Now, the markup contains two elements with  ID `tagOne` which is invalid markup.

You can use class instead of ID.

1. Select any of the element from the two(`.tagOne` or `.tagTwo` in this case)
2. Use [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to select the sibling element having the other class
3. Use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to select closest ancestor matching the selector.

The step #1, #2 and #3 above will select only those `.item` elements having both `.tagOne` and `.tagTwo` as descendent.

**Code:**

```
$('.tagOne') // Select one of the element
  .siblings('.tagTwo') // Get second element if it is sibling
  .closest('.item') // Get the closest ancestor
```

```js
$('.tagOne') // Select one of the element
  .siblings('.tagTwo') // Get second element if it is sibling
  .closest('.item') // Get the closest ancestor
  .addClass('selected'); // For Demo purpose
```

```css
.item {
  color: red;
}
div.selected {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="items">

  <div id="block1" class="item">
    <span class="tagOne tag">One</span>
    <span class="tagTwo tag">Two</span>
  </div>

  <div id="block2" class="item">
    <span class="tagOne tag">Java</span>
  </div>

  <div id="block3" class="item">
    <span class="tagTwo tag">I Love JavaScript</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

You can also use `filter` as follow.

1. Iterate over all the `.item` elements using [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)
2. Use [context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) to check if the current `.item` has descendent `.tagOne` and `.tagTwo`.
3. Use [`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) property on the jQuery object to get the number of elements selected by the selector.

**Code:**

```
$('.item').filter(function() {
  return $('.tagOne', this).length && $('.tagTwo', this).length;
})
```

```js
// Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8tuu1wxs/1/

// Iterate over all elements having item class
$('.item').filter(function() {
  return $('.tagOne', this).length && $('.tagTwo', this).length;
}).addClass('selected');
```

```css
.item {
  color: red;
}
.selected {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="items">

  <div id="block1" class="item">
    <span class="tagOne tag">One</span>
    <span class="tagTwo tag">Two</span>
  </div>

  <div id="block2" class="item">
    <span class="tagOne tag">Java</span>
  </div>

  <div id="block3" class="item">
    <span class="tagTwo tag">I Love JavaScript</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

**If the sequence/order of the elements is fixed,** CSS [general sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) or [adjacent sibling selector `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) can be used.

```
$('.tag1 ~ .tag2').closest('.item')
```

OR

```
$('.tag1 + .tag2').closest('.item')
```

```js
// Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/amdoLfou/1/

$('.tag1 ~ .tag2') // + can also be used instead of ~
  .closest('.item') // Get closest ancestor
  .css('color', 'blue'); // For Demo purpose
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="items">

  <div id="block1" class="item">
    <span class="tag1 tag">One</span>
    <span class="tag2 tag">Two</span>
  </div>

  <div id="block2" class="item">
    <span class="tag1 tag">Java</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure how this works or understand this question. But anyway, your attempt is nice.

Comment: The second one, that's the same thing I did, didn't I?

Comment: @PraveenKumar NO! In your code, you were checking if any of the element is present.`> 0`. So, it'll return `true` even when any one of the element is present.

Comment: can we make it simpler with `$('.tagOne.tagTwo')`?

Comment: @AnkitKathiriya NO! That selector will select elements having both the class. You want to check if two elements contain each one class. And if that has worked, I'd have added that as my first answer. :)

Comment: @DavidThomas, PraveenKumar Thank You! Feels good to hear appreciation from fellow devs. :)

Comment: @Tushar Thanks for this, this works and returns the correct divs! If I could expand (as I'm struggling to adapt your solution to be more dynamic)... The filter criteria (i.e. `tagOne`, `tagTwo`) will be of uncertain size and I'm currently concatenating the users selection. For example "`tagOne,tagTwo,tagThree`" etc... How could this be integrated into your answer so that it isn't as 'hard-coded'?

Comment: @Smittey Can you create live demo on jsfiddle and share the link

Comment: @Tushar Sure https://jsfiddle.net/Lgtaoudj/ - So it needs to be able to accommodate an unknown number of tags, such as a third tag `tagThree`

Comment: @Smittey [Here's my try to make the selectors more dynamic](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/Lgtaoudj/1/). You can just change the array of selectors and the code will filer the elements accordingly. [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/Lgtaoudj/2/)

Comment: Perfect. Much appreciated @Tushar

Comment: Welcome @Smittey. Glad to help :)

Comment: You're welcome indeed, though you flatter me slightly: I'm simply a mere hobbyist :)

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer, I felt that this is a question worthy of a plain JavaScript, rather than simply a jQuery, solution. So, with that in mind, I'd like to offer the following approach (which does use some ECMAScript 6 feastures, so does require a fairly modern browser):

```
// using an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression syntax,
// so that the enclosed function will be executed when
// encountered, rather than requiring the user to call it
// explicitly (this would need to run in a DOMReady callback
// or once the DOM has been constructed, however):
(function hasAll(opts) {

  // setting the default settings for the function:
  var settings = {
    // a CSS Selector string to identify the ancestor
    // element that you wish to identify:
    'ancestorSelector': 'div',

    // an array of CSS Selectors to identify the
    // descendants by which the ancestor should
    // be found:
    'descendantSelectors': []
  }

  // looking at the named (not inherited) properties
  // of the opts Object supplied by the user:
  for (var property in opts) {

    // if the opts Object has a given property
    // name we set the corresponding property
    // of the settings Object to be equal to that
    // property-value:
    if (opts.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      settings[property] = opts[property];
    }
  }

  // finding all the elements represented by the first selector
  // of the user-supplied selectors contained within an element
  // matching the ancestor selector:
  var firstElements = document.querySelectorAll(
      settings.ancestorSelector + ' ' + settings.descendantSelectors[0]
    ),

  // converting the NodeList returned by document.querySelectorAll()
  // into an Array, using Array.from:
    arrayOfFirsts = Array.from(firstElements),

  // here we iterate over that Array, using Array.prototype.filter():
    hasSiblings = arrayOfFirsts.filter(function(n) {

      // we look for the parentNode of the current node (n):
      var p = n.parentNode;

      // we use Array.prototype.every() to ensure that every
      // selector in the descendantSelectors Array returns
      // a Node (document.querySelector() returns only the
      // first node matching the given selector, or null if
      // there is no element matching that selector).
      // if Array.prototype.every() returns true (all elements
      // of the Array match the supplied test) then the current
      // node (n) is retained in the array returned by
      // Array.prototype.filter():
      return settings.descendantSelectors.every(function(selector) {

        // Array.prototype.every() returns a Boolean,
        // true : if all elements of the Array match
        //        the supplied test/assessment,
        // false: if *any* of the elements of the Array
        //        fail to match.
        // this is the test that we're matching against:
        return p.querySelector(selector) !== null;
      });
    });

  // here we iterate over the hasSiblings Array, and use
  // Array.prototype.map() to form a new Array, using
  // an Arrow function to take the current node (n)
  // and find, and return, the closest element to that
  // node which matches the supplied settings.ancestorSelector:
  var found = hasSiblings.map(n => n.closest(settings.ancestorSelector));

  // returning that array to the calling context:
  return found;

})({
  // this is the 'opts' Object that we're passing to the
  // IIFE-contained function:
  'ancestorSelector': '.item',
  'descendantSelectors': ['.tagOne', '[data-demo]']

// using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the
// returned elements, to add the class 'hasAll' to the
// the classList (the list of class-names) of the given
// node (n):
}).forEach(n => n.classList.add('hasAll'));
```

```js
(function hasAll(opts) {
  var settings = {
    'ancestorSelector': 'div',
    'descendantSelectors': []
  }

  for (var property in opts) {
    if (opts.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      settings[property] = opts[property];
    }
  }

  var firstElements = document.querySelectorAll(
      settings.ancestorSelector + ' ' + settings.descendantSelectors[0]
    ),
    arrayOfFirsts = Array.from(firstElements),
    hasSiblings = arrayOfFirsts.filter(function(n) {
      var p = n.parentNode;
      return settings.descendantSelectors.every(function(selector) {
        return p.querySelector(selector) !== null;
      });
    });
  var found = Array.from( hasSiblings.map(n => n.closest(settings.ancestorSelector)) );
  return found;

})({
  'ancestorSelector': '.item',
  'descendantSelectors': ['.tagOne ~ .tagTwo']
}).forEach(n => n.classList.add('hasAll'));
```

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hasAll {
  border-color: #f90;
}

.hasAll span {
  color: #f90;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="items">

  <div id="block1" class="item">
    <span class="tag tagOne">One</span>
    <span class="tag tagTwo">Two</span>
  </div>

  <div id="block2" class="item">
    <span class="tag tagOne">Java</span>
  </div>

  <div id="block3" class="item">
    <span class="tag tagOne" data-demo="false">tag-one</span>
    <span class="tag tagTwo">tag-two</span>
    <span class="tag" data-demo="true">tag-three</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fas7zc6o/1).

Note that, with the above function, an ancestor element will be matched if any of its descendants', or its descendants' siblings, matches multiple selectors.

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
- [`for...in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).
- [`Object.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).

Comment: An interesting solution, thanks for this! Also works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 blocks.filter('.item').find('[id="tagOne"],[id="tagTwo"]');
```

Comment: [This Doesn't Work!](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8tuu1wxs/3/). I suggest you to delete this answer. If you think this works, add a live demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `has` [jquery has selector](https://api.jquery.com/has/) it searches if selected nodes have certain children:
https://jsfiddle.net/96gbf7xg/